# Переместить элемент ссылочного вектора

Tags: c++, vector

Есть ссылка на вектор

```
vector<CCMD> &commands = *new vector<CCMD>();
```

Как через неё переместить элемент в оригинальном векторе?

`swap` как-то непонятно работает с ссылками, он меняет местами элементы в ссылке, но не в оригинале.. я сам ничего не понял.

```
swap(commands[i], commands[i + 1]);
```

**UPD**

Код:

```
commands = bots[0]->command.commandListChat;
...

cout << "copy - " << commands[i].instance->triggerS << endl;
cout << "orig - " << bots[0]->command.commandListChat[i].instance->triggerS << endl;
swap(commands[i], commands[i + 1]);
cout << "copy - " << commands[i].instance->triggerS << endl;
cout << "orig - " << bots[0]->command.commandListChat[i].instance->triggerS << endl;
```

Вывод:

```
copy - 2
orig - 2
copy - 1
orig - 2
```

**UPD2**

Я понял. Изменить ссылку нельзя. Очень интересно. Пойду всё переделывать.

Comment: а может там все таки копирование? или COW?

Comment: `vector<CCMD> &commands = *new vector<CCMD>();` - и как потом память освобождать? `delete &commands;`? Не лучший метод - по целому ряду причин...

Comment: так нельзя писать, это UB

Answer (score 2):

Ссылка - это точный псевдоним, так что нельзя "изменить в ссылке", не изменив в оригинале. По сути, как бы вы ни работали со ссылкой - вы работаете с оригиналом. Это - не копия!

Все вполне [работоспособно](https://ideone.com/5QG0rp):

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> a = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    vector<int> &c = a;

    for(auto i: a) cout << i << " "; cout << endl;

    swap(c[2],c[3]);

    for(auto i: a) cout << i << " "; cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. Я сейчас сам в недоумении, но оригинал не меняется. Если вместо ссылки написать путь до оригинала - всё работает

Answer (score 0):

```
commands = bots[0]->command.commandListChat;
```

Не в ссылках дело, вы только-что здесь сделали копию вектора. По-подробнее код пожалуйста.

Comment: Что подробнее? У меня 3 вектора. В зависимости от ситуации мне нужно менять ссылку на один из векторов, а это сделать нельзя, о чём я написал в конце.